# How to set alpha to the constraintlayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]

Above Attachment I am setting alpha to the backdrop but the textview is also getting the blur effect how can I just set the alpha to only Imageview and not to the textview.
I am not nesting any layout inside the constraint layout so I am not able to understand which parent view gets the alpha property so the only imageview gets the transparent.
Please ignore the poster name and movie name ;)

My xml code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nseit.com.tmdb.Discover.view.MovieDetailsView">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/posterbackdrop"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/largebackdrop"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="@string/interstellar"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView7" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    style="@style/MyTabLayout"
    android:theme="@style/TabLayout_Theme"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/TextColor"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
```

Comment: I believe the alpha is being set correctly. The 'effect' above is probably due to difference in contrast b/w white and a translucent image. Try with more contrasting colors to verify.

Comment: Check if `@color/white` is really pointing to `#FFFFFFFF` or `#FFFFFF`

Comment: did you find any solution for this?